# Django. Загрузка файла на сервер без формы

Tags: python, django, файлы, загрузка

Есть модель:

```
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    attach = models.FileField(upload_to='media/')
```

Генерирую pdf документ. На выходе получаю переменную типа `<class 'bytes'>`. Как мне сохранить сгенерированный файл в модель.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `FileField.save` (это класс поля `revsys.attach`) принимает любой file-подобный объект, благодаря чему можно не записывать его в ФС заранее, а просто создать в памяти с помощью [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO):

```
from io import BytesIO

revsys = UploadFile()
revsys.attach.save('file.pdf', BytesIO(pdf), save=True)
```

Это работает в Django 1.10, где file-подобный объект оборачивается в джанговый класс `File` автоматически. Если вы используете Django 1.9 или старее, оно будет ругаться ошибкой `'_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'size'`, и здесь придётся обернуть BytesIO самостоятельно:

```
from django.core.files import File
# ...
revsys.attach.save('file.pdf', File(BytesIO(pdf)), save=True)
```